# Prove this sequence of recursively defined sets converges to the natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of sets $\{\phi_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ recursively defined by the relation

$$\phi_k=\left\{ \frac{a_{k-1}-2^q}{3} \in\Bbb{N} : a_{k-1}\in\phi_{k-1},\  q\in\Bbb{N},\ 2^{q+1} \mid a_{k-1}\right\}$$

And we take $\phi_0=\{2^q: q\in\Bbb{N}\}$. I wish to prove that the sequence $\{\phi_k\}$ converges to $\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ in the sense that

$$\forall_{n\in\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}\ \exists_{K}\text{ s.t. } \forall_{k\ge K} n\in\phi_k \ \ \ \text{ and }\ \ \ \ \phi_k\subseteq\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\} $$

It's not terribly difficult to show that $\phi_0\subseteq\phi_1\subseteq\phi_2\subseteq\ldots\subseteq\phi_k$ (multiply the explicit equation for elements of $ \phi_k $ below by 3), so it suffices to show

$$\forall_{n\in\Bbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}\ \exists_{k}\text{ s.t. } n\in\phi_k$$

(note that $\phi_k\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ and does not contain $0$ by construction). As an example of how things proceed, one can show with a bit of direct calculation that $\phi_1=\left\{\frac{2^{q_0}-2^{q_1}}{3}\in\Bbb{N}: q_0>q_1\in\Bbb{N}\right\}$ consists of all natural numbers with representation in base 4 given by 111...1100...000 or 222...2200...000 where there may be any number of 1's,2's, or 0's in the string (so long as it is nonzero).

More explicitly, the elements of $\phi_k$ are precisely the set of integer solutions to the equation

$$3^k*x=2^{q_0}-3^0*2^{q_1}-3^1*2^{q_2}-...3^{k-1}*2^{q_{k}}$$

For some choice of $q_0>q_1>q_2...>q_{k}\ge 0$ (to see how the recursion relation falls out of this equation, consider the equation modulo $ 3^{k-1}$). For example, $10=2*4^1+2*4^0 = 22$ in base 4, so $10\in\phi_1$, and we can write $3^1*10=2^5-3^0*2^1$. Similarly, $21=111$ in base 4, and $3^1*21=2^6-3^0*2^0$

I'm not terribly familiar with results of set theory regarding treatment or convergence of recursive sequences, so I'd also appreciate any pointers in the way of applicable theorems.

---

EDIT 1:

I'll add updates that I feel are elucidating as I develop them. Advice and insights on progress are welcome.

The set $\phi_k$ is characterized by a base set $B_k$ of odd numbers such that

$$\phi_k=\left\{ 2^qb_k: b_k\in B_k, q\in \Bbb{N}\right\}$$

And the sets $B_k$ satisfy the recursion relation

$$B_k=\left\{\frac{2^qb_{k-1}-1}{3}\in\Bbb{N}:b_{k-1}\in B_{k-1}, q>0\in\Bbb{N}\right\}$$

The desired proof reduces to showing that the sequence $\{B_k\}$ converges (in the same sense as above) to the set of positive odd numbers, where $B_0=\{1\}$. This formulation is particularly useful in that we can immediately see how any $b_{k-1}\in B_{k-1}$ determines the elements of $B_k$:

If $b_{k-1} \not\equiv 0 \pmod3$ (otherwise, $b_{k-1}$ generates no elements in $B_k)$, it determines a sequence ${\{\psi_p(b_{k-1})\}_{p=0}^{\infty}}\subseteq B_k$ with

$$\psi_0=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2b_{k-1}-1}{3}, & b_{k-1} \equiv 2 \pmod3 \\
\frac{4b_{k-1}-1}{3}, & b_{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod3 \\
\end{cases}$$

and satisfying the recurrence relation (to see where this comes from, see the recursion relation of $B_k$)

$$\psi_p=4\psi_{p-1}+1 $$

and thus $$\psi_p=4^p\psi_0+4^{p-1}+4^{p-2}+\ldots 4+1$$
and so $\psi_p$, in base 4, is the string $\psi_0$ concatenated with p 1's. Finally, we construct $B_k$ as

$$B_k=\mathop{\bigcup}_{b\in B_{k-1}} \{\psi_p(b)\}_{p=0}^{\infty}$$

where $\{\psi_p(b)\}=\emptyset$ if $b \equiv 0 \pmod3$.
We can immediately see from this (and that $\psi_0(1)=1$) that $B_1$ is the set of natural numbers with base 4 representation 111...111 where there are any nonzero number of 1's in the string, in agreement with the above conclusion.

With some direct calculation using the elements of $B_1$, one finds that $B_2$ is the set of natural numbers with base 4 representation 1301301...301301111...111 or 3203203...203203111...111, the strings 301 or 203 are repeated any number of times, and there are any number of 1's appended on to the end, and thus $\phi_2$ is the set of natural numbers that are $2^q$ times these elements of $B_2$.

Though the calculations seem more natural in base 4, the results are much more interesting in base 2. The elements of $B_1$ in base 2 are 101010...10101, while the elements of $B_2$ are 111000111000...11100011010101...0101 or 111000111000...1110001010101...0101 (the difference being the number of 1's between the switch from the 111000111000... repetition to the 01010101... repetition, either of which may occur any number of times). The entirety of $\phi_2$, then, is given by these numbers with any number of $0$s on the end.

As an example, $1110001101_2 = 909_{10}$, so $909\in\phi_2$, and $3^2*909=2^{13}-3^0*2^{3}-3^1*2^0$, so 909 is indeed a solution to the explicit equation for the elements of $\phi_2$.

(After some further investigation, the apparent symmetry of results in base 2 does not seem to generalize past $B_2$.)

---

EDIT 2:

To generalize the results of the previous edit on the form of $B_2$, we consider a sequence of elements of $B_{k-1}$, call it $\{\Psi_p\}_{p=0}^\infty\subseteq B_{k-1}$, that satisfies a recursion relation

$$\Psi_p=4^q\Psi_{p-1}+c \text{  for some  } q,c\in\Bbb{N}$$

and thus

$$\Psi_p=4^{jq}\Psi_{p-j}+c*(4^{(j-1)q}+4^{(j-2)q}+ \ldots +4^q+1) \text{ for } 0< j \leq p$$

We wish to consider how this might give rise to a sequence of elements in $B_k$. We evaluate

$$\psi_0(\Psi_p)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2\Psi_p-1}{3}, & \Psi_p \equiv 2 \pmod3 \\
\frac{4\Psi_p-1}{3}, & \Psi_p \equiv 1 \pmod3 \\
\end{cases}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2*[4^{3q}\Psi_{p-3}+c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)]-1}{3}\\
\frac{4*[4^{3q}\Psi_{p-3}+c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)]-1}{3}\\
\end{cases}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{4^{3q}*(2\Psi_{p-3}-1)+4^{3q}+2c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)-1}{3}\\
\frac{4^{3q}*(4\Psi_{p-3}-1)+4^{3q}+4c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)-1}{3}\\
\end{cases}\\=
\begin{cases}
4^{3q}\psi_0(\Psi_{p-3})+\frac{4^{3q}+2c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)-1}{3}\\
4^{3q}\psi_0(\Psi_{p-3})+\frac{4^{3q}+4c*(4^{2q}+4^q+1)-1}{3}\\
\end{cases}$$

Note that we relate $\psi_0(\Psi_p) \text{ to } \psi_0(\Psi_{p-3})$ to ensure that the numerator in the result is divisible by 3. In addition, $\Psi_p \equiv \Psi_{p-3} \pmod 3$, so we may relate $\psi_0(\Psi_{p-3}) \text{ to } \psi_0(\Psi_{p-6})$ in the same way, and so on, and thus the above result establishes a recurrence relation for a sequence of elements of $B_k$. What's more, *this relation is of the same form as that for $\{\Psi_p\}$*, with $q\rightarrow 3q$ and a new $c$, so discussion of these sequences is relevant for all $\phi_k$. If $c\not\equiv0\pmod3$, then $\exists_p$ s.t. $\Psi_p\equiv1\pmod3$ AND $\exists_p$ s.t. $\Psi_p\equiv2\pmod3$, and so the sequence $\{\Psi_p\}$ in $B_{k-1}$ bifurcates into two distinct sequences in $B_{k}$. If $c\equiv0\pmod3$, then we have $\Psi_p\equiv\Psi_{p-1}\pmod3$, and $\{\Psi_p\}$ gives rise to a single sequence in $B_k$ (or none at all, if $\Psi_p\equiv0\pmod3$) with recurrence relation

$$ \psi_0(\Psi_p)=
\begin{cases}
4^q\psi_0(\Psi_{p-1})+\frac{4^q+2c-1}{3}, & \Psi_0 \equiv 2 \pmod3 \\
4^q\psi_0(\Psi_{p-1})+\frac{4^q+4c-1}{3}, & \Psi_0 \equiv 1 \pmod3 \\
\end{cases}$$

Each element in these sequences in $B_k$ serves as an initial value for another sequence $\{\psi_p(b)\}$ (as defined in Edit 1) for some $b\in B_{k-1}$.

To see the use of these results, consider the case of going from $B_1$ to $B_2$: the elements of $B_1$ are a sequence $\{\Psi_p\}$ with a relation defined by $q=1$ and $c=1$, so there are two sequences of elements of $B_2$; one with $q=3$ and $c=35_{10}=203_4$, and one with $q=3$ and $c=49_{10}=301_4$, as found previously.

Comment: Terminology: We do not say that a sequence $(\phi_k)_k$ converges to a set $S$ unless we have some definition of what it means for $\phi_k$ to be "close to" $S.$  (Is this a language translation difficulty?) What you asking is to prove the equation $\cup_{k=0}^{\infty}\phi_k=\mathbb Z^+$..... BTW what does $\phi_2$ look like?

Comment: Thanks; I'm writing an update now that will add a definition of what I mean by convergence (your condition is equivalent). I'll try to include a description of $\phi_2$ as well.

Comment: There are two notations that I have seen  only rarely: If $(s_n)_n$ is a sequence of sets then $x\in \lim \sup s_n$ iff $\{n:x\in s_n\}$ is infinite, and $x\in \lim \inf s_n$ iff $\{n:x\not \in s_n\}$ is finite.  I think it is rare because it's rare: If you use it you should define it because most people won't know it, but  if you define it you didn't need to say $\lim \sup$ or $\lim \inf$  anyway

Comment: I've added some to my edit, including a complete description of $\phi_2$. While the addendum is a bit long, the added exploration is very fruitful.